# article used in place of possesive pronoun

Tags: definite-article, possessive-pronoun

I've stumbled on a construction that confused me in Kafka's *Die Verwandlung* where a **definite article** is used where I would expect to see a **possessive pronoun**.

> wenn er **den** Kopf ein wenig hob
>
> translation: (if he lifted his head a little)
>
> my faulty translation: (if he lifted **the** head a little)

Could **seinen** also be used here, and if so, would it change the meaning in any way, and if not, how do I know when to use an **article** vs a **possessive pronoun** for these types of constructions.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other answer tells us when it is necessary to use the possessive. This question asks about the difference in meaning between the two.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The other question asks exactly the same thing, the only answer merely fails to adequately address the difference in meaning.